# 2 player game about removing powers

Tags: game-theory

Two players play a game with $n$ counters. Taking turns,
each player must remove a number of counters which is a power of $d$. The
person who removes the last counter wins. For any general value of $d$,
determine for which values of $n$ the first player has a winning strategy,
and for which values of $n$ the second player wins.

Attempt case $d=2$: in this case I sum the binary version of $n$ and if it is even the first player loses, if odd they win.

Comment: Counterexample: start with $5$ (ie. $101$ in binary). 
The first player will take $2^1 = 10_{(2)}$ in binary. What will be left is $3 = 11_{(2)}$. The second player will take either 1 or 2. And the first player wins.   But the sum of $101$ is even.

Comment: This is an interesting question OP, but it still needs context. Where did this came from? Coursework? A textbook? A contest? Research? This would help someone have an idea whether this is known to be solvable, for one thing.

Comment: Exercise 6.5 solving mathematical problems by Terence Tao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will split natural numbers into two sets, winning $W$ and losing $L$, with properties:

1. $0 \in L$
2. For any number in $W$, there is a move that gives number in $L$.
3. For any number in $L$ other then $0$, any move gives number in $W$.

Then it's clear that 1st player wins iff $n \in W$.

We can take $W$ and $L$ such as:

- $x \in W$ if $x \mod {d + 1}$ is either odd, or equal to $d$
- $x \in L$ if $x \mod {d + 1}$ is even and not equal to $d$

1. If $x \in W$ and $x < d$, then $x \mod {d + 1}$ is odd. The only possible move will give $x - 1$, which is either $0$, or even $\mod d + 1$, thus in $L$.
2. If $x \in W$ and $x = d$, then move "take $d^1$" gives us number $0 \in L$.
3. If $x \in W$, $x > d$ and $x \mod {d + 1}$ is even, then move "take $d^0$" gives us number that is odd $\mod d + 1$ and not equal to $d$, thus in $L$.
4. If $x \in W$, $x > d$ and $x = d \pmod {d + 1}$, then move "take $d^1$" gives us number equal to $0 \mod {d + 1}$, thus in $L$.
5. If $x \in L$ and $x \ne 0 \pmod {d + 1}$, then any move will either decrease or increase $x \mod {d + 1}$ by $1$, thus giving us number that is even $\mod {d + 1}$ and thus in $W$.
6. If $x \in L$ and $x = 0 \pmod {d + 1}$, then any move will give us number that $\mod d + 1$ is either $1$ or $d$, and thus again in $W$.

Note that if $d$ is odd, then $W$ is just set of all odd numbers, $L$ is set of all even numbers, and strategy doesn't matter: any move that takes even number gives an odd, and vice versa.

Comment: For $(3)$ should the implication be that it gives us a number that is even $\mod d+1$

Comment: For $(6)$ I guess the implication should be "and thus in W".

Comment: Correct on both, thanks.